# Need to store Objects, so that on refresh, the object should be available in angularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I have a Service implemented. And i'm creating two Objects.
After refresh their values are becoming null.

how should I store these objects, so that i can access them after refresh also.

```
var userPool = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool(xyz);
var cognitoUser = AWSCognito.authenticate(userpool);
```

this is implemented in a service, so it will run only once.
Now i need to store these objects, so that i can access them even after refresh.

Comment: When you say refresh, do you mean page refresh? And are you using a web browser as client?

Comment: You'll need to user localstorage: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-local-storage

Comment: @aliasav : yes, web browser

Comment: For data persistence within the app, services should be used, while for data persistence within the browser, localstorage should be used. Attached a link in the previous comment, please check. Also, read about localstorage here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: any way we can implement this using angular constants.

Comment: No, since as soon as you refresh the page, your angular-app will reload and all variables/consts will be reset. The only way to persist data across sessions is using localstorage in the client side. Other than localstorage you can used IndexDB and other browser DBs as well, but localstorage should solve your purpose

Answer (score 1):

For data persistence within the app, Services should be used.

For data persistence within the browser, localstorage should be used.

Read about localstorage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

An angular library for localstorage:
https://npmjs.com/package/angular-local-storage

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the option of - [localstorage](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage).

local storage for angular that implemented on the native one.

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript LocalStorage:

```
localStorage.setItem("userPool", userPool);
localStorage.setItem("cognitoUser", cognitoUser);


localStorage.getItem("userPool");
localStorage.getItem("cognitoUser");
```

you can also use **angular localstorage** library that has more flexible API.

[Angular LocalStorage](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage)

Comment: Is there any other way except localstorage and sessionStorage and web database.

Comment: i think it's pretty that's it. those all three have the same idea (to save the data in thebrowser), your other option of course is you database.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

1. Store it in  a database and every time the application loads for the first time (like after a refresh) read the data once from the DB.
2. Store it in [localstorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) and read it when the app starts
3. [IndexDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) - internal browser database (please note the [support metrics](http://caniuse.com/#search=indexdb))

Answer (score 0):

Best option is to use angular local storage.
https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage/

Comment: Hi Shiva, welcome to StackOverflow! Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.